# Which fonts support ligatures in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

Where can I find a list of fonts that support ligatures for MS Word ?

I have done several searches for this online and found nothing yet.

Even on [Office support](https://support.office.com/en-us/Search/results?query=ligatures&src=as) I cannot find a list.

Comment: from your link: "For ligatures to display, the font that you use must contain ligature characters. Not all fonts contain ligatures", so this question is not specific to Word.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I only want to know which of he fonts in Word can use ligatures, yes its not specific to work, but I am only interested specifically in the Word options

Comment: Since fonts can come from many sources, you would either need to find a utility that can examine the font file and report on it, such as otfinfo, or you would need to contact the foundry that supplied the font and ask. Or, you could just try enabling the feature in Word; if the font supports it, Word will use it; if not, enabling will have no effect.

Comment: Note that there are at least three separate ligature-related features - standard ligatures, discretionary ligatures, and historical ligatures - which may be independently supported or not-supported by any particular font.

Comment: Also note that different fonts that support the same ligature feature may have different ligatures defined, so merely supporting ligatures may not have what you want.

Comment: Word does not have fonts. Word is word processing software. The fonts are handled by the OS. Every font that has ligatures in the place where ligatures are expected will work in software that accesses the ligatures where they are expected.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams There was a time when MS Word _did_ come with fonts: When purchasing Word you also got a number of fonts. Arial Unicode MS springs to mind.

Answer (score 4):

Some examples of standard Windows fonts containing ligatures are Times New Roman, Calibri, Sylfaen and Tahoma.

But your question could have been clearer. Were you looking for a particular ligature? The "Th" one for example, not many fonts have that one. (Only Times out of the four above.)

Or was your question about how to enable display of ligatures in Word? Bring up the Fonts dialog by pressing Ctrl+D (at least in my version), then click the Advanced tab and adjust the settings under OpenType features.

If this doesn't answer your question, please let me know and we'll see what we can do.